# Replacement of light switch connected by wires of 5 different colours

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

My light switch is connected by wires of 5 colours. After breaking the original one, I tried to replace but no idea about the colours, no label on the connector.

Black and white were twisted together.
Orange and grey were twisted together.
Yellow was on its own.

Any help on how to connect the new switch would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: We need more information such as what type of switch  is this and what is it being used to control. A picture or 2 and a better explanation would be useful.

Comment: What country is this? Do you have the new switch in hand?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: You should make it clear why you can't simply reconnect the two wires that were previously connected. What's the exact problem?

Comment: There's no need to get creative. Connect the new switch the same way the old one was connected.